2D Projections of 3D Models
Currently working on taking pictures of models for image recognition training. Ive confirmed that the files work by running them in blender where everything gets loaded correctly (correctly using the obj file to find the mtl file, containing the PNG paths, and using the coordinates from obj to correctly place the textures.
The current code I have (and I apologize for the monstrosity im new at this);
import os
import open3d as o3d
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import random

def generate_2d_projections(mesh, output_folder, filename, num_projections=6):
    os.makedirs(output_folder, exist_ok=True)
    
    vis = o3d.visualization.Visualizer()
    vis.create_window(visible=False)
    vis.add_geometry(mesh)
    
    ctr = vis.get_view_control()
    # Total degrees is 360, spread over the number of projections
    rotation_increment = int(360 / num_projections) * 20  # Adjust the multiplier if necessary

    for i in range(num_projections):
        random_color = [random.random() for _ in range(3)]
        vis.get_render_option().background_color = random_color
        # Rotate the view; you may need to adjust the multiplier for correct visual representation
        ctr.rotate(rotation_increment, 0)
        vis.poll_events()
        vis.update_renderer()
        
        image = vis.capture_screen_float_buffer(False)
        image = np.asarray(image)
        image.setflags(write=1)
        image = (image * 255).astype(np.uint8)
        img = Image.fromarray(image)
        img.save(os.path.join(output_folder, f"{filename}_projection_{i}.png"))
    
    vis.destroy_window()

def process_all_models(input_folder, output_folder):
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(input_folder):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.obj'):
                file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                output_subdir = os.path.join(output_folder, os.path.basename(subdir))
                filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]  # Extract filename without extension
                try:
                    mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh(file_path, True)
                    if not mesh.has_triangles():
                        print(f"Skipping {file_path}: no triangles.")
                        continue
                    if mesh.has_triangle_uvs():
                        print(f"{file_path} has texture coordinates.")
                        generate_2d_projections(mesh, output_subdir, filename)
                        print(f"Processed {file_path} successfully.")
                    else:
                        print(f"{file_path} does not have texture coordinates. Skipping.")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Failed to process {file_path}: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_folder = "C:/Users/Simen/wow.export"
    output_folder = "C:/Users/Simen/Documents/Backend/Wownerd/2d_images"
    process_all_models(input_folder, output_folder)

My codes models
Blenders model
Example obj/mtl/png;
https://github.com/LienSimen/objmtl
If anyone has any suggestions im all ears, the reason im not doing it in blender is because I need to take a million pictures and that will be very time consuming
